# Core Data sync with CouchBase using CBLIncrementalStore crashing

Tags: swift, core-data, couchbase-lite

I am using Core Data in my project and now I wanted to add sync features. Rolling my own turned out to be harder than I thought; therefore, I wanted to try ready libraries.

I integrated Couchbase in the project, setup IBM Cloudant for sync gateway and server.

For a very simple project I tested it and everything seems to be working fine. However, when I implement the same solution to the existing project; it crashes sometimes and I don't have the slightest clue how to approach the problem.

p.s. Info if it makes a difference: I had hell of a time with the model update in CBLIncrementStore as the core data kept complaining that it can't modify an immutable model; event though it was not used or attached to persistent store. In the end I had to create a new project, modified the model, and copy the model to my existing project. Then it started working. Even below code, where returning an mutableCopy of the model; didn't work (event though it worked perfectly in an empty project):

**EDIT** - Normally, no need to return mutableCopy this is something I tried in my particular case. Explained above^^

```
// MARK: - MODEL
lazy var modelURL: URL = {
    let bundle = Bundle.main
    if let url = bundle.url(forResource: "couchsync", withExtension: "momd") {
        return url
    }
    DLog("CRITICAL - Managed Object Model file not found")
    abort()
}()

lazy var model: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    if let mutableModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: self.modelURL)?.mutableCopy() as? NSManagedObjectModel {    
        return mutableModel
    }
    DLog("CRITICAL - Can't read model")
   abort()
}()
```

The code crashes below in CBLIncrementalStore:

```
- (NSIncrementalStoreNode*) newValuesForObjectWithID: (NSManagedObjectID*)objectID
                                         withContext: (NSManagedObjectContext*)context
                                               error: (NSError**)outError {
```

And the debug output is as follows (CDStack.swift is from my project):

```
[00324]:CDStack.swift                  :save.......................... :16:15:14 Inserted objects count = 33
2017-04-11 16:15:14.132 MuhApp[23391:1022666] -[__NSCFNumber _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000001
2017-04-11 16:15:14.142 MuhApp[23391:1022666] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000001'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c6e3b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bba0141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c753134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c66a840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c66a3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreData                            0x000000010c1e9cfd _PFRawFastIndexForKnownKey + 93
    6   CoreData                            0x000000010c1e9bfe _PFRawIndexForKnownKey + 62
    7   CoreData                            0x000000010c1ea49c -[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 objectForKey:] + 28
    8   MuhApp                              0x000000010a184639 __66-[CBLIncrementalStore newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_2 + 121
    9   CoreData                            0x000000010c239b52 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 178
    10  CoreData                            0x000000010c239a1f -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 239
    11  MuhApp                              0x000000010a18449e __66-[CBLIncrementalStore newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 670
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011351405c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001134f1de6 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 346
    14  MuhApp                              0x000000010a184033 -[CBLIncrementalStore newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 403
    15  CoreData                            0x000000010c2ea624 __95-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 100
    16  CoreData                            0x000000010c2f32f4 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 196
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011351405c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001134f1de6 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 346
    19  CoreData                            0x000000010c2e0785 _perform + 213
    20  CoreData                            0x000000010c2e0505 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeLightweightBlock:toStore:] + 229
    21  CoreData                            0x000000010c211d01 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 417
    22  CoreData                            0x000000010c211218 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 376
    23  CoreData                            0x000000010c210c9f _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 239
    24  CoreData                            0x000000010c2341e2 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _includeObject:intoPropertyWithKey:andIndex:] + 130
    25  CoreData                            0x000000010c2339c0 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 576
    26  Foundation                          0x000000010b6a96dc NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 351
    27  Foundation                          0x000000010b6a8f93 NSKeyValueDidChange + 484
    28  Foundation                          0x000000010b679709 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 111
    29  CoreData                            0x000000010c21c40d -[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:] + 93
    30  CoreData                            0x000000010c2a773f -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _updateFromRefreshSnapshot:includingTransients:] + 799
    31  CoreData                            0x000000010c23fe54 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _copyChildObject:toParentObject:fromChildContext:] + 948
    32  CoreData                            0x000000010c23f413 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] + 947
    33  CoreData                            0x000000010c2ba927 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 567
    34  CoreData                            0x000000010c23a0ea internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 106
    35  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011351405c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001134f1de6 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 346
    37  CoreData                            0x000000010c23a054 _perform + 244
    38  CoreData                            0x000000010c239e7d -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 301
    39  CoreData                            0x000000010c221488 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 3368
    40  MuhApp                              0x000000010a215522 _TFZFC6MuhApp7CDStack4saveFCSo22NSManagedObjectContextT_U_FT_T_ + 610
    41  MuhApp                              0x000000010a1a0927 _TTRXFo___XFdCb___ + 39
    42  CoreData                            0x000000010c239b52 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 178
    43  CoreData                            0x000000010c239a1f -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 239
    44  MuhApp                              0x000000010a21529b _TZFC6MuhApp7CDStack4savefCSo22NSManagedObjectContextT_ + 187
    45  MuhApp                              0x000000010a1ded49 _TFC6MuhApp7MUStoreP33_5810EFAD2D482DA23D84CA4C96F2558221createbusinessFoldersfT_GSaCS_9MUAccount_ + 11145
    46  MuhApp                              0x000000010a1db875 _TFC6MuhApp7MUStoreP33_5810EFAD2D482DA23D84CA4C96F2558228fetchOrCreateBusinessFoldersfT_GSaCS_9MUAccount_ + 133
    47  MuhApp                              0x000000010a1d4e78 _TFC6MuhApp7MUStoreg15businessFoldersGSaCS_9MUAccount_ + 120
    48  MuhApp                              0x000000010a236fa0 _TFC6MuhApp23MainTableViewController7preparefT3forCSo17UIStoryboardSegue6senderGSqP___T_ + 1088
    49  MuhApp                              0x000000010a2380fb _TToFC6MuhApp23MainTableViewController7preparefT3forCSo17UIStoryboardSegue6senderGSqP___T_ + 187
    50  UIKit                               0x000000010dc158ee -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 353
    51  UIKit                               0x000000010dc1575c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    52  UIKit                               0x000000010dc15a1f -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 157
    53  UIKit                               0x000000010d5a4d77 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1677
    54  UIKit                               0x000000010d5a4fe3 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 344
    55  UIKit                               0x000000010d45a7f3 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318
    56  UIKit                               0x000000010d4477bc _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 532
    57  UIKit                               0x000000010d47928c _afterCACommitHandler + 137
    58  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c689717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    59  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c689687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    60  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c66e720 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
    61  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c66e016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    62  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110359a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    63  UIKit                               0x000000010d44e0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    64  MuhApp                              0x000000010a2a9da7 main + 55
    65  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011356065d start + 1
    66  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: FWIW, all managed object models are mutable until you load some data using them. Then you can't mutate them any more. Getting a `mutableCopy` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I know; however, in my case it didn't work (was getting can't modify an immutable model error). That is the reason I specifically put it there. Getting the mutableCopy made the project work but resulted in weird crashes. Then I deleted the model, and used one created in an empty project which I modified for my purposes then copied over to this existing project. Then it worked. Of course I deleted returning the mutableCopy; there was no need.